# How to convert InstrumentedAttribute to Float (SQLAlchemy Python)?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to return eateries from a sql table (with sqlalchemy) that are within a specific distance to a user. I'm passing in the user's lat and long coordinates as well as the eateries coordinates to filter out the ones that are too far

```
results = (
        Eatery.query
        .filter(
            distance(user_long, user_lat, Eatery.longitude, Eatery.latitude) <= max_distance
        )
        .all()
    )
```

Problem is when it gets passed to the distance method (which im sure is correct) it gets sent as an InstrumentedAttribute and I have no idea how to convert it to a float

I've tried casting and stuff it doesnt work.